# Запятая пред "чтобы"?

Tags: пунктуация

1. В Анисовку из города приехал новый участковый, чтобы навести там порядок.
2. Из города в Анисовку приехал новый участковый(,) навести порядок.
3. В Анисовку из города прислали нового участкового(,) навести порядок.
4. Я пришел сюда, чтобы предупредить вас о том, что к нам едет участковый.
5. Я пришел  сюда () предупредить вас о том, что к нам едет участковый.

Обычно перед "чтобы", как правило, ставится запятая. А если союза "чтобы" нет, но он подразумевается, в каких тогда случаях ставится или не ставится запятая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Группа 1**

В Анисовку из города приехал новый участковый, чтобы навести там порядок.

Структура двух  других предложений для варианта без обособления не подходит, требуется ее перестройка.

В Анисовку из города приехал навести порядок новый участковый.

Из города в Анисовку приехал новый участковый - навести порядок. В Анисовку из города прислали нового участкового - навести порядок.

Для обособления используется **тире** как более сильный знак, что связано **с расположением инфинитива в роли обстоятельства на расстоянии.**

**Группа 2**

Я пришел сюда, чтобы предупредить вас о том, что к нам едет участковый.

Я пришел сюда предупредить вас о том, что к нам едет участковый.

Грамматика верная в обоих случаях, но стилистически более приемлемо второе предложение с одним придаточным. Запятая не ставится: **пришел предупредить, инфинитив в роли обстоятельства цели.**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Существует мнение, что в русском языке свободный порядок слов, но свобода эта относительная. В действительности, любое изменение в порядке слов отражается на смысле или стиле сообщения, кроме того, **"беспорядок" слов просто недопустим.**

У всех членов предложения есть своя нормальная позиция, изменение нормативного порядка характерно для художественной речи и публицистики, при этом автор чаще всего интуитивно применяет различного вида инверсии.

Вот предложение:  **Из города в Анисовку приехал новый участковый навести порядок.** Это как раз пример беспорядка слов: два обстоятельства, затем инверсия подлежащего и сказуемого, затем обстоятельство цели. Где тут тема (предмет), где рема (сообщение о предмете). Как его вообще прочитать, как ударение тонические (подъем и понижение тона) расставить?  Получается не предложение , а унылое бормотание на одной ноте.

А вот пример из Шукшина: **Он даже не умывАлся, а шел сразу во двОр - колоть дрова.** Очень художественная картинка, ударение определяет противопоставление: не умывался, а шел во двор. Для главных членов инверсии, разумеется, нет.

Но что интересно, здесь обособление обязательным не является: **Он даже не умывАлся, а шел сразу во двор колоть дровА.**  Логика сообщения уже связана непосредственно с дровами, а не с двором. Сочетание "шел сразу во двор колоть дрова" построено как управляющий глагол и три отнесенных к нему обстоятельства, и такая строгая последовательность позволяет определить функцию инфинитива как обстоятельства и при дистантном расположении.

Таким образом, **дистантное расположение необособленного инфинитива допускается при  соблюдении порядка слов внутри сочетания**, тогда в составе предложения мы имеем единую смысловую единицу.

Comment: >> **Структура двух других предложений для варианта без обособления не подходит, требуется ее перестройка.** Бездоказательно, но поразительно безапелляционно. Сказано Верой — значит, верно? "Из города в Анисовку приехал новый участковый навести порядок" -- что не так? Ваш вариант тоже возможен, они абсолютно равноправны, просто акценты разные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Короче, я так понял, в примерах: Из города в Анисовку приехал новый участковый() навести порядок.
В Анисовку из города прислали нового участкового() навести порядок. Или тире, или ничего, запятые ставить нельзя. Но если вставить на место скобок союз "чтобы", то запятая появляется, хотя смысл и порядок слов не изменяются.

Comment: А если "навести порядок" принять как добавочное обстоятельство?

Comment: Niemand, ваши сообщения меня всегда радуют, просто удовольствие доставляют, а теперь вы даже стихами заговорили (можно мы будем с вами на "простое" вы?). А разница вот в чем: в моем предложении сочетание  "приехал навести порядок" построено по правилам, то есть инфинитив стоит после глагола, а в исходных примерах - на расстоянии.

Comment: Угрюм, тут такое дело. Если инфинитив (обстоятельство) стоит после  глагола (сказуемого), то его синтаксическая роль ясно видна, обособления не требуется. На расстоянии инфинитив должен обособляться, причем как присоединительный член, то есть при отсутствии присоединительных союзов с помощью тире, а не запятой.  А когда появляется союз "чтобы", мы уже имеем СПП с придаточным цели, тогда ставится запятая.

Comment: Вера, а вы и правило это покажете? Но я вам тогда приведу сотню примеров из худ. литературы (хоть классики, хоть современной), где это гипотетическое правило не соблюдается. Причем из признанных стилистов. Мы же не всегда говорим "Мама мыла раму"? Подлежащее-сказуемое-прямое дополнение?

Comment: Niemand, давайте начнем с вас. Задание такое: вы в произведениях наших классиков находите ИНФИНИТИВ  в роли ВТОРОСТЕПЕННОГО члена предложения (обстоятельства, дополнения, определения), расположенного на РАССТОЯНИИ от управляющего слова и НЕ ОБОСОБЛЕННОГО от него.

Comment: Нет, пардон. Покажите мне правило. Ведь вы как сказали? "Структура двух других предложений для варианта без обособления не подходит, требуется ее перестройка". Иными словами, предложения построены синтаксически неверно. Это очень сильное утверждение, треба подтвердить правилами.

Comment: Непременно будет информация. Но вы себя внимательно читаете? Получается, если я даже найду правило, то вы все равно приведете сотню примеров, его отрицающих.  Вы тогда хотя бы один пример приведите, чтобы мне было понятно, какое правило вы от меня ждете.