# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "чтобы"?

Tags: пунктуация

Он уже был озабочен мыслями о затычке для уха, которую нам предложили для того чтобы нырять в воду.

Comment: Одну затычку нам предложили? Маловато будет. И запятых тоже мало на три предложения, надо бы две.

Comment: Затычка нужна для того, чтобы защищать больное ухо. Одно

Comment: Обратите внимание, подобный вопрос уже задавался: [Запятая пред "чтобы"?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417328/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это СПП**: "*Он уже был озабочен мыслями о затычке для уха*" - главное предложение, "*которую нам предложили для того*" - придаточное определительное, "*чтобы нырять в воду*" - придаточное цели. **Перед обоими придаточными предложениями должны быть поставлены запятые**: первая запятая перед словом "которую", **вторая - перед словом "чтобы"**.