# Дистантное расположение инфинитива-обстоятельства

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой справочный материал можно найти по этому вопросу. Именно в случае дистантного расположения, не «пойду посмотреть/посмотрю» и т. п.

Пример из И. А. Бродского:

*И поднимет барбос лай на весь причал
//не признаться, что рад, а что одичал.*

Поднимет... лай на весь причал не признаться.
Инфинитив цели — признаться. Очень хотелось бы ознакомиться с регламентирующими правилами :)

Comment: Нашел подобную тему, но без приведения правила [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417328/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Воротиться сюда через двадцать лет,
 отыскать в песке босиком свой след.
 И поднимет барбос лай на весь причал
 не признаться, что рад, а что одичал.
                Иосиф Бродский. Итака
```

*И поднимет барбос лай на весь причал / **не признаться, что рад, а что одичал.***

1. Запишем содержание предложения с использованием **придаточных цели и причины:**  *И поднимет барбос лай на весь причал **не чтобы**  признаться, что рад, а **потому что** одичал.*

Мы видим, что при наличии частицы ***НЕ*** запятая не ставится, поэтому нет знака препинания и **в стихотворении**. Содержание фразы там **предельно свернуто**, но при этом понятно читателю.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)** 4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится: 1) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит **отрицательная частица НЕ:** В море, в качке, спишь **не когда** хочешь, **а когда** можешь (Гонч.).

2. Определить существительное инфинитивом в этом тексте не получится: **лай (какой?)**. Кроме того, здесь дистантное расположении инфинитива.
3. **Правила обособления инфинитивных определений**

Постановка **тире** регулируется  **[ПАС под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)**

**Правило для инфинитива**

§ 60. Несогласованные определения, выраженные **инфинитивом,** обычно **не обособляются**, они образуют вместе с именем существительным **словосочетание:** желание учиться, приказ выехать, идея создать общество милосердия, мечта заняться искусством, распоряжение выполнить задание. Например: **Я дал команду залечь и приступить** к изучению оборонительной системы противника (Зл.); Нужно иметь мужество признать и свою неудачу (Копт.); Кирилл Иванович ощущал в себе желание повторять каждое слово по нескольку раз, но почему-то боялся делать это (М. Г.).

**Также надо  учитывать общее правило:**

§ 57. Обособляются несогласованные определения, **отделенные от определяемых слов** — существительных и местоимений — другими членами предложения: Тотчас, вся в летнем прозрачном солнце, склонилась над ним Мария Щербатова (Пауст.); В легком воздушном платье, вошла она в комнату и села напротив окна.

Comment: Спасибо за Бродского)